# m2eclipse addDependency not suggesting artifacts

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

for a while now, when I try to addDependency with m2eclipse, the only org.* dependency suggested is the one seen in the pic. A while ago, it would actually suggest a lot of possible dependencies to me. I have not changed anything that I know of, and now it doesn't work anymore. Anyone know what I can do to make this work again? Any cache I can clear?

[image]